# AsyncCallback function never getting executed

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am implementing a program to sniff all traffic and filter it down to find a certain string. I have the same exact code working in a different project adopted from this project:

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C
```

The Asynccallback is not firing the `OnReceive` method in this line.

```
mainSocket.BeginReceive(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
```

it does not complain or throw an exception it will execute the line just fine but it will not execute `OnReceive`

Comment: Does the data receives? What is the length of buffer? Did you tried synchronous read?

Comment: Did you check `CompletedSynchronously` in the `IAsyncResult` returned by `BeginReceive`?

Comment: yes data has some stuff in it.. not readable without the parser though, @JimRhodes CompletedSynchronously is false and it has not completed

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint to make sure OnReceive it's not null at that point?

Comment: yes I did, it does not get into OnReceive so it is null at this point, it completely ignores the call